# Select Attributes in multiple Excel slicer and Applied Together on Chart simultaneously

Tags: excel, sharepoint, charts, ssas

We have a Pivot Chart in Excel using lots of slicers to filter it. That Chart has Connected to SSAS to show multidimensional Data.

If we want to filter Chart, you Must choose Slicer1 , change its attribute , it will be applied on chart , then Slicer2, Change, Apply , ..... have lots of time consumtion for end user.

How can We select some attributes in more than one slicer and apply it to chart simultaneously؟

Some link like [Multislicers Selection](http://www.contextures.com/exceladvancedfilterslicers.html)
work with flat files but I need it for Charts and SSAS connections

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using Filters instead of Slicers as they get evaluated together, not individually.  Take a look at this [6 WAYS TO IMPROVE THE SPEED OF MICROSOFT POWER PIVOT REPORTS](https://www.blue-granite.com/blog/6-ways-to-improve-the-speed-of-microsoft-power-pivot-reports)

Alternatively, you can force the connection to be manual only and either trigger by right clicking on the connection and refreshing or with a little script / Refresh button on the screen, however this leads to a less intuitive user interface

Comment: Thanks, but how can I prevent connection to updated after clicking on each slicers?